# Why is LICQ automatically satisfied in Linear Optimization Problems?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Why is LICQ automatically satisfied in Linear Optimization Problems?
I tried to proof it by showing that gradients are always linear indepedent
but thats not the case. It depends on the number of active inequalities.
Can anybody help me with this proof?

Comment: What is LICQ?  Something something constraint qualification?

Comment: Linear Independence Constraint Qualification = active gradients are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

The Linear Independence Constraint Qualification is NOT always satisfied in linear optimization problems, in particular when the gradients (rows of coefficients) of the active constraints are not independent.

However, the Linearity Constraint Qualification is always satisfied for linear optimization problems. Because the objective function and constraints of a linear optimization problem are continuously differentiable, the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions are always necessary for linear optimization problems. Furthermore, because the objective function and constraints are convex, KKT are also sufficient for linear optimization problems, i..e, KKT are necessary and sufficient for all linear optimization problems.