# LICQ not satisfied for optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

what are the consequences when the linear independant constraint qualification (LICQ) does not hold?

so when im looking for KKT points numerically, do i possibly get points that arent even optimums? or do i simply miss out on some optimums because they do not satisfy the KKT conditions.

thank you guys!

Comment: Was your previous question on LICQ adequately answered? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710233/why-is-licq-automatically-satisfied-in-linear-optimization-problems/3710312#3710312

Comment: yes it was :))))))

Comment: Then you should upvote and accept it.